# How can I prevent duplicates from printing

Tags: sas

In the following code, I would like to remove the duplicates inside the columns cd,id,se,nt,dd. Usually, when duplicates appear, the appear in the NT column with a "-" first. But in general they are duplicates in all columns. Thanks in advance!

```
PROC PRINT DATA=data.data2;
var cd id SE NT DD;
format notional commax32.;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a `proc sort` before the `print` with the `nodupkey` option to remove any duplicates:

```
proc sort data=data.data2 nodupkey;
  by cd id se nt dd;
run;
```

Or, if you want to preserve your original data, you can output the result of the `proc sort` to a new table:

```
proc sort data=data.data2 out=data3 nodupkey;
  by cd id se nt dd;
run;

PROC PRINT DATA=data3;
var cd id SE NT DD;
format notional commax32.;
run;
```